# Alfresco, Batch disable inheritance on a huge amount of Folders

Tags: alfresco, batch-processing, alfresco-share

I have an Alfresco Folder with 10000 + Children Spaces, and they are inheriting a specific role that I want to remove.

Is there any way, either by Alfresco's UI or even programmatically, to disable the inheritance for each child Space ?

The only way I've managed to do this from the UI (either /share or /alfresco ) is  by picking each child and disabling it, one-by one, and that's really not an option

I also have some scripts that disable the inheritance, and while they work for one folder, when executed in a loop (fetching children on a java thread on runtime, using paging) they produce exceptions after some iterations, so I guess I'd have to dig really deep to sort this out

Thanx for any suggestions,

p.s : my Alfresco version is Alfresco 4.2.c-2

EDIT: I should make clear that in my scenario, I cannot simply disable the inheritance on the parent folder, because of the Repository design/ structure. And I really think a UI option to for batch disable inheritance is a very helpful and needed option, so I still hope that there should be an option I'm missing.

Comment: Either you use a common subfolder with the permissions configuration you need for the Child spaces, or you set all of them to not inherit permissions. Can you share the script that's not working for you?

Comment: Tank you for the help. As I updated my question, disabling inheritance on the parent folder is not an option either. About the script, it's a pretty complex code using the deprecated WebService API, and if I had to to the job pragrammatically, I'd probably need to write a new code anyway...